# Return only issues using PyGithub

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygithub

I'm trying to get the number of issues in a repository, but the code below is returning issues and pull requests.  How do I just get issues?  I think I'm missing something simple here.  I read the api documentation and it states GitHub treats all pull requests as issues.

```
repo = g.get_repo("someRepo")
label = repo.get_label('someLabel')
myIssues = repo.get_issues(state='open',labels=[label])
count = 0
for issue in myIssues:
    count = count + 1
print(count)
```

Comment: Hi. Is there anything about a pull-request that would distinguish it by a non-pull request, data wise?

Comment: I see this note in the GitHub docs: GitHub's REST API v3 considers every pull request an issue, but not every issue is a pull request. For this reason, "Issues" endpoints may return both issues and pull requests in the response. You can identify pull requests by the pull_request key.

Comment: That sounds promising for your particular concerns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For issues which are just issues, the `pull_request` is `None`.

```
>>> repo = g.get_repo("PyGithub/PyGithub")
>>> open_issues = repo.get_issues(state='open')
>>> for issue in open_issues:
...     print(issue)
...
Issue(title="Correct Repository.create_git_tag_and_release()", number=1362)
Issue(title="search_topics returns different number of repositories compared to searching in browser.", number=1352)
>>> print(open_issues[0].pull_request)
<github.IssuePullRequest.IssuePullRequest object at 0x7f320954cb70>
>>> print(open_issues[1].pull_request)
None
>>>
```

So you can count only those issues for which issue.pull_request is `None`.

```
repo = g.get_repo("someRepo")
label = repo.get_label('someLabel')
myIssues = repo.get_issues(state='open',labels=[label])
count = 0
for issue in myIssues:
    if not issue.pull_request:
       count = count + 1
print(count)
```

You can also replace your count logic as follows:

```
count = sum(not issue.pull_request for issue in myIssues)
```